# Dissecting the img src attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to display an image on a click. This works fine by storing the source of the image into a variable like so..

```
var theSrc = $(event.target).attr('src');
```

I can then put this image into a div and display it

```
var theImg = '<div class="wrap"><img src="'+imgSrc+'"></div>';
```

What I would like to do, would be to simply alter the source of the image slightly to a larger file in the same directory that is bigger by appending "Big" to the name

```
image.png
```

to

```
imageBig.png
```

Is this possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use `.replace()` - it's simpler than `.split()` for this use:

```
var theSrc = $(event.target).attr('src').replace( '.png', 'Big.png' );
```

Also a suggestion: I would eliminate noise words like `the` from your variable names. Instead of `theSrc`, use `src`. Instead of `theImg`, use `img`. The word `the` doesn't communicate anything at all and has no value in a variable name. It actually has *negative* value, because it's extra stuff to read that doesn't add any meaning to the simpler name.

Comment: I see how `the` could be added to avoid confusion between src the attribute, img the element and theSrc or theImg the jQuery variables. Though it's only conventions (I would avoid using such confusing names and prefix them by a $ as they're jQuery variables, in the first place)

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
var theSrc = $(event.target).attr('src');
theSrc = theSrc.split(".")[0] + "Big." + thetheSrc.split(".")[1];
```

Comment: What if there is another `.` in the `src` attribute? e.g. `src="temp.test/image.png"`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary -- I should address that, a reg-ex would work, or just split on `.png` or whatever default img extension is, then replace it all. Either way.

Comment: This works to, just selected answer was a quicker implementation for this scenario

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
$("img").attr("src", "imageBig.png");
```

See the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2  There are multiple flavors of attr that you can use.

To do it dynamically, see @tymeJV's post, which will work as long as there is only one period in the file name.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to add "Big" to the end of whatever the img src was? Did I read completely wrong?

Comment: I think he wants it to be dynamic, not just for 'image' to 'imageBig'

Answer (score 1):

Not with jQuery, but you can do it with Javascript:

```
var temp = imgSrc.split('.');
var newSrc = temp[0]+'Big.'+temp[1];
```